# How can I install Unreal engine on a PC with metered connection or completelly offline?

Tags: unreal-4, windows, installer

I need to get Unreal Engine 4 as soon as possible on my desktop PC, in order to complete a task. However, the computer is on a metered connection and downloading it there would cost me about 3 pizzas worth of money.

I have a laptop which I can bring somewhere where there is WiFi. But I see that Unreal Engine only provides an online installer, judging from the fact that the installer has 40MB.

So how could I install Unreal on my laptop, then move it to this desktop PC? I don't mind using some data if it needs to connect to the internet to verify my account, but I don't want to download over 10GB over mobile data unless it's absolutely necessary.

It must be Unreal Engine 4 specifically, I cannot use something else, nor I wish to.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to install the Unreal Engine to an external hard drive and run it on any PC you like through a USB connection.  A number of people do this so their engine and all their projects can be worked on in a number of locations.

You need to make sure that the PC you're trying to run it on has the require prerequisites (VS C++ 2015 I think) but these are downloaded as well into the Unreal Engine folder and can be installed later if needed.

Comment: I will test this thanks a lot. I am going to the city today, so I will test it in the evening. Do you think I will be able to then move Unreal to my main PC? I'd rather run it from an SSD.